# A script that writes errors and should create a event-error

Tags: function, vbscript, while-loop, event-log

this if it works should check the internet connection if there is a connection it does nothing. if there isn't a connection it should write a error in a txtfile if that happend 5 times it should create a error but it doesn't

I will show you the whole code that i have now and the piece of code that i want in a loop. I can't get it in the way i want. I want it to creat 1 Event-error after 5 times writing to the file.

this is the whole code i will put the code i want in a loop under it

```
strDirectory = "Z:\text2"
strFile = "\foutmelding.txt"
strText = "De connectie is verbroken" 
strWebsite = "www.helmichbeens.com"


If PingSite(strWebsite) Then WScript.Quit    'Website is pingable - no further action required
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

RecordSingleEvent
Dim fout 
For fout = 1 To 5 : Do
    If fout = 5 Then Exit Do

        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Call WshShell.LogEvent(1, "Test Event")
Loop While False : next

'------------------------------------
'Record a single event in a text file
'------------------------------------
Sub RecordSingleEvent
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, 8, True)
    objTextFile.WriteLine(Now & strText)
    objTextFile.Close
End sub
'----------------
'Ping my web site
'----------------
Function PingSite( myWebsite )
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://" & myWebsite & "/", False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MyApp 1.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    On Error Resume Next
    objHTTP.Send
    PingSite = (objHTTP.Status = 200)
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------
'Counts the number of lines inside the text file
'-----------------------------------------------
Function EventCount(fout)
    strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile,ForReading).ReadAll
    arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)
    EventCount = UBound(arrLines)
End Function
```

This is the whole code, and it doesnt work correctly becaus it creats a event-log rightaway and it should do that after the script has written 5 times to the textfile

here is the code that writes to a textfile

```
Sub RecordSingleEvent
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, 8, True)
    objTextFile.WriteLine(Now & strText)
    objTextFile.Close
End sub
```

and here is the code but this part doesnt not work or atleast i think it is this part

```
Dim fout 
For fout = 1 To 5 : Do
    If fout = 5 Then Exit Do

        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Call WshShell.LogEvent(1, "Test Event")
Loop While False : next

Function EventCount(fout)
    strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile,ForReading).ReadAll
    arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)
    EventCount = UBound(arrLines)
End Function
```

this is the not working part and I don't know what to do anymore so can you please take a look at it tank you very much.

btw: this code can be very usefull for a network administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do something very weird with your `for do while false next loop`. The early escape can also be done with the for loop itself:

```
Dim fout, WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") ' Get this out of the loop, you only have to create it once.

For fout = 1 To 5
    if fout = 5 then exit for
    Call WshShell.LogEvent(1, "Test Event")
next
```

I would recommend using `Option Explicit`. You use lots of variables I never see initialized. Furthermore, you use `ForReading` this is not an VBScript keyword, you have to assign it the proper value. You can make it a Global Constant:

```
Const ForReading = 1
```

You would have spotted that if you used Option Explicit.

Try to make function that will work on their parameters and not external global variables. So refactor the `EventCount` function to:

```
Function EventCount(logFilePath)
    dim strData, arrLines
    strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logFilePath, ForReading).ReadAll
    arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)
    EventCount = UBound(arrLines) + 1
End Function
```

Did you notice that `fout` is never used in the EventCount function?

You also want to increment the EventCount with 1, because an array is zero indexed (ubound will return -1 for empty arrays). Count is alway defined as the exact amount of items in contrary to the index.

EDIT: reading your logic, I think you want to do this:

```
Dim fout, objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Ping the website five times
For fout = 1 to 5
    If PingSite(strWebsite) Then Exit For    'Website is pingable - no further action required

    ' The website was not pingable, write it to a logfile
    RecordSingleEvent

    ' The website was not pingable five times in a row, log it to the eventlogger
    If fout = 5 then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Call WshShell.LogEvent(1, "Test Event")
    End if

Next

' We are done.
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer it does work but, I find out that it aint the thing that i am looking for :P